# Why legend does not appear outside plot?

Tags: python, matplotlib, pycharm, legend

I run code from this answer [How to put the legend out of the plot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4700614/how-to-put-the-legend-out-of-the-plot/43439132#43439132) in PyCharm in console (Anaconda environment) and it didn't produced right output

I recreated a conda env, but it still does not work.

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = np.linspace(0,2*np.pi)
colors=["#7aa0c4","#ca82e1" ,"#8bcd50","#e18882"]
fig, axes = plt.subplots(ncols=2)
for i in range(4):
    axes[i//2].plot(x,np.sin(x+i), color=colors[i],label="y=sin(x+{})".format(i))

fig.legend(loc=7)
fig.tight_layout()
fig.subplots_adjust(right=0.75)   
plt.show()
```

**Expected**: what's presented in answer.

**Actual** in PyCharm (SciView) [image: pycharm]
**Actual** in prompt [image: prompt]

Comment: If you run the same code outside of pycharm but with the same conda environment, does it produce the desired output?

Comment: Yes https://i.imgur.com/3gPMHrF.png

Comment: Ok; I have no idea what PyCharm is doing.

Comment: I created ticket https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-37023. If someone could confirm if he/she/they have the same effect I'd be grateful.